# Bug lista de usuários react native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou tentando listar uma lista de usuários do banco de dados, mas ela não carrega quando inicia o aplicativo e nem se eu atualizar o emulador do android studio pressionando 'RR', já testei em meu celular e também acontece a mesma coisa, mas o estranho é que se eu der um ctrl+s no vscode (que estou utilizando para codar) a lista carrega. Estou utilizando hooks e o firebase para fazer isso; para que desse certo a listagem, tive que utilizar o list.push(), creio que seja isso que esteja bugando o aplicativo, eu deveria utilizar setList(), mas o setList() só roda uma vez dentro do snapshot.forEach(), andei pesquisando e descobri que fazer isso não é uma boa prática, então o que posso fazer para listar os usuários e tirar esse bug?

Aqui está o código:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

export default function App(){
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const [load, setLoad] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function loadList(){
            if(list.length < 1){
                let ref = await firebase.database().ref('usuarios');

                const listener = await ref.on('value', (snapshot)=>{
                    snapshot.forEach((childItem)=>{
                        let key = childItem.key;
                        let nome = snapshot.child(key).val().nome;
                        let idade = snapshot.child(key).val().idade;

                        list.push({ key, nome, idade });     
                    });

                    return () => listener()

                });
                setLoad(false);
            }
        }
        loadList();
    }, []);

    if(load){
        return <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='#CCC'/>
    }else{
        return (
            <View>    
                <FlatList
                    data={list}
                    renderItem={({item})=><Text>{item.nome}</Text>}
                /> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

coloquei um `if(list.length < 1)` porque a lista quando carregava, estava carregando duplicado, não sei o porque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se é isso, mas acredito que o problema seja porque você está alterando a variável do estado diretamente. Crie uma variavel por fora para alterar. As variaveis de estado não são feitas para serem atualizadas manualmente e sim usando o setState delas. Exemplo:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    async function loadList(){
        if(list.length < 1){
            let ref = await firebase.database().ref('usuarios');

            let dataToLoad = [];

            const listener = await ref.on('value', (snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.forEach((childItem)=>{
                    let key = childItem.key;
                    let nome = snapshot.child(key).val().nome;
                    let idade = snapshot.child(key).val().idade;

                    dataToLoad.push({ key, nome, idade });     
                });

                return () => listener()

            });

            setList(dataToLoad);
            setLoad(false);
        }
    }
    loadList();
}, []);
```

Só que nesse caso ele vai renderizar a tela duas vezes pois vc está setando o list e o load. Eu recomendo que vc crie um estado só assim:

Primeiro criando um state inicial fora da função:

```
const initialState = {
    load: false,
    list: []
}
```

Depois ao criar o estado passe a initial state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)
```

Quando for setar os valores, use o spread para trazer o estado atual mais os novos campos:

```
setState({ ...state, load:true, list: dataToLoad })
```